# Why isn't .hover function working and how can I get the .hover function to ignore the the area outside of the corner radius?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover

I'm trying to get circles to react to my jquery .hover. Here's my js:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
this.css("position","absolute");
this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
return this;
};


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#logo').center();
    j=8;
    size=200;
    $.each($(".circle"), function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', j);
        $(this).css({
            height: size+"px",
            width: size+"px",
            borderRadius: size+"px",
            });
        size = size+50;
        $(this).center();
        j--;
    });

});

  $(".circle").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        height: '+=25px',
        width: '+=25px',
        top: '-=12.5px',
        left: '-=12.5px'
        }, 'fast'
      );
    },
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        height: '-=25px',
        width: '-=25px',
        top: '+=12.5px',
        left: '+=12.5px'
        }, 'fast'
      );
    }
  );
```

Here's my body HTML:

```
    <div id='logo'><img src='_Source/Logo.png' alt='RB'/></div>
<div id='a1' class='circle'></div><div id='g1' class='circle'></div>
<div id='a2' class='circle'></div><div id='g2' class='circle'></div>
<div id='a3' class='circle'></div><div id='g3' class='circle'></div>
<div id='a4' class='circle'></div><div id='g4' class='circle'></div>
```

This works on jsfiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wdbphoto/bHGRW/3/)

But, on my site it doesn't work, [here](http://www.wdb.us/RB)

If I weren't bald already, I'd be tearing my hair out.

Thanks.

Comment: The jsfiddle and your site have different code. I simply copypasted the circle hover part from jsfiddle, executed in the site console and it works..

Comment: On a side-note. Not sure if this is intentional or not but in your fiddle when you move the mouse quite hectic for about 20 seconds or so across the divs/image, eventually the circles become off-set. Just wondering if the maths are off a bit.

Comment: @Esailija Are you talking about the HTML or the JS?

Comment: @wdbphoto specifically the hover binding js, nothing else. Copypasta started from `$(".circle").hover(`...

Comment: @Esailija I just copy and pasted the code over just to be sure and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.hover()` binding call is located outside of the scope of your `.ready()` binding, and is located in the `<head>`.   The net effect is you are attempting to bind the `.hover` callback before the DOM has been loaded.    The simplest way to address this is to move it into the scope of your .ready() bound function.

Comment: Whoops, I feel like an idiot now. Thanks. Do you have any idea as to how I can get the hover to disregard the area outside the border radius?